# Polish letters lost

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am trying to get rtf formatted text from database and get plain text out of it but i am having trouble with some of polish letters. Not all of them just few.
In database there is stored line which looks like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\deflang1045{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset238 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Raport s\'b3u\'bfy do kontroli kwot na fakturach.\par  Wy\'b3apuje rozbie\'bfno\'9cci w kwotach por\'f3wnuj\'b9c warto\'9cci z tabelek InvoiceDetail i AccountSettlement\par  }
```

after getting it out of database i store it in String then i use this method:

```
    private String rtfDecode(String input) {
    try{
    RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
    Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
    rtfParser.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()), document, 0);
    String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
    return text;
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Most part seems to be fine but i am loosing polish letters

```
Raport s³u¿y do kontroli kwot na fakturach.
Wy³apuje rozbie¿ności w kwotach porównuj¹c wartości z tabelek InvoiceDetail i AccountSettlement
```

It should look like this

```
Raport służy.....
```

I think i am doing something wrong with coding but i cant find what is the problem

Comment: Looks like an issue with your character encoding?

Comment: have you tried UTF-16? some say it helps

Comment: Your problem is caused by the broken swing RTF parser. To fix this you'll have to use a third party library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223903/java-rtf-parser for more info.

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try using another library