# Extract string content from rtf string java

Tags: java, regex, rtf

I've following rtf string: `\af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid6361256 Study Title: {Test for 14431 process\'27s \u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \u8805 8000}}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid12283827` and I want to extract the content of Study Title ie (`Study Title: {Test for 14431 process\'27s \u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \u8805 8000}`). Below is my code

```
String[] arr = value.split("\\s+");
//System.out.println(arr.length);
for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
    if(isNumeric(arr[j])) {
         arr[j] = "\\?" + arr[j];
    }
}
```

In above code, I'm splitting the string by space and iterating over the array to check if there is any number in string, however, `isNumeric` function is unable to process `8000` which is after `\u8805` because its getting the content as `8000}}{\rtlch\fcs1`. I'm not sure how I can search the Study title and its content using regex?

Comment: Suggest you use an RTF parser. See [Java RTF Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17223903/5221149).

Comment: Hi @Andrea I can use  RTF parser, however I'm not sure If I can get the unicode chars as I want to update the contents of my Study Title string. That's the reason I'm not using RTF parser as it will display the plain text without those unicode chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Study Title: {[^}]*}` will match your expect.  Demo: https://regex101.com/r/FZl1WL/1

```
    String s = "{\\af31507 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\insrsid6361256 Study Title: {Test for 14431 process\\'27s \\u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \\u8805 8000}}{\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af31507 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\insrsid12283827";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Study Title: \\{[^}]*\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

output:

```
Study Title: {Test for 14431 process\'27s \u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \u8805 8000}
```

Update as per OP ask

```
String s = "{\\af31507 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\insrsid6361256 Study Title: {Test for 14431 process\\'27s \\u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \\u8805 8000}}{\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af31507 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\insrsid12283827";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Study Title: \\{)[^}]*(?=\\})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

Test for 14431 process\'27s \u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \u8805 8000
```

Comment: Hi @yudong thanks for answer. Also how can I get the content only like 'Test for 14431 process\'27s \u8805 1000 Testing2 14432 \u8805 8000' rather with study title and without start '{'  and ending '}' ?

Comment: @shanky, just update pattern to (?<=Study Title: \\{)[^}]*(?=\\})

Comment: Hi @yudong its giving me java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition error